# High resolution video preview Youtube

Tags: iphone, xml, youtube

Through their API Google offers the possibility to search through feeds of Youtube with XML and JSON (for example through this page http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ijustine/uploads/ )

Now there is an preview image element in there, but it only has an 480 * 320 resolution. Is it possible to get an higher resolution version? Currently I am using these previews for an iPhone app only on the 960*640 screen it looks really jaggy.

Thanks.

Comment: How large is your preview rect? 240*180(retina) seems acceptable already for previewing

Comment: The preview image is 480 * 320. I want to display it on 640 * 480. That would cover the entire width of the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the highest resolution thumbnail generated from YouTube is 480 width (http://i.ytimg.com/vi/13LLqmWz0G8/0.jpg OR http://i.ytimg.com/vi/13LLqmWz0G8/hqdefault.jpg )

If you don't want to scale the image to fit your image rect, you will need to capture the image from the mp4 directly by using `MPMoviePlayerController` with function:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option;
```